# "warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding." but my system isn't embedded either, why is grub trying?

Tags: grub2

I'm reading myself for the release of Jessie on Debian, so I'm extra cautious (should be said paranoid) about any message that can cause problems, namely warnings. My system is a desktop with Debian testing/unstable installed, on ext4 partitions for both `/boot` and `/`, yet I'm seeing this message while upgrading the `grub-pc` package in Debian:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
```

Why is grub saying that my system is embedded? What is the cause of this? I tried to check the grub-install binary, but I couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: This is nor about your system being embedded. `embed` is a Grub command: "Embed the Stage 1.5 STAGE1_5 in the sectors after the MBR if [...]". I don't understand what is supposed to be the problem with `ext2`, though.

Comment: Apparently grub calls ext3 and ext4; ext2, so the warning is fine, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1095142). It seems the embedding vs blocklists warning is about where grub is being installed, MBR vs partition boot sector.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are getting the warning because you are installing grub to a partition instead of the MBR.  This means grub can not be embedded in the unused space between the MBR and the first partition.  Instead it has to have the list of blocks that `/boot/grub/core.img` resides in placed into the MBR.  This setup is subject to being broken by things like defrag and so is not recommended, hence the warning.  Since it is only a warning, you can ignore it.

Comment: So... I just had to deselect the partition on the package configuration.

Answer (score 126):

Most people coming to this from a search engine are probably wondering, "why do I get this error?":

```
warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding. 
warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their  use is discouraged.. 
error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Because you did, e.g.:

`grub-install /dev/sda1`

instead of

`grub-install /dev/sda`

I.e. tried to install to a partition instead of the MBR.

Comment: I know I reinstalled grub, and I did it with grub-install /dev/sda. I still got the warning.

Comment: You got a warning, and it continued? Or an error?  This is primarily about overcoming that error.

Comment: I ran `apt dist-upgrade` on Debian, and it idiotically asked me to reselect where GRUB should go (as if I know!). I indeed selected /dev/sda1 (my /boot partition). Now it doesn't boot. If I boot a live distro and run grub-install, it gives that embedding complaint and refuses to proceed. Repairable?

Comment: @Boann, I happened to work with a similar problem here https://askubuntu.com/a/531051/149881  Maybe it will help you.

Comment: dammit, you deserve all the beers.

Comment: I had this error for two days. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: This error can also happen from trying to install GRUB to a disk that has no partitions.

Answer (score 5):

I quote from Grub2's `info` pages:

> MBR
>    ====
>
> The partition table format traditionally used on PC BIOS platforms is
>   called the Master Boot Record (MBR) format; this is the format that
>   allows up to four primary partitions and additional logical partitions.
>   With this partition table format, there are two ways to install GRUB:
>   it can be embedded in the area between the MBR and the first partition
>   (called by various names, such as the "boot track", "MBR gap", or
>   "embedding area", and which is usually at least 31 KiB), or the core
>   image can be installed in a file system and a list of the blocks that
>   make it up can be stored in the first sector of that partition.
>
> Each of these has different problems. There is no way to reserve
>   space in the embedding area with complete safety, and some proprietary
>   software is known to use it to make it difficult for users to work
>   around licensing restrictions; and systems are sometimes partitioned
>   without leaving enough space before the first partition. On the other
>   hand, installing to a filesystem means that GRUB is vulnerable to its
>   blocks being moved around by filesystem features such as tail packing,
>   or even by aggressive fsck implementations, so this approach is quite
>   fragile; and this approach can only be used if the `/boot' filesystem
>   is on the same disk that the BIOS boots from, so that GRUB does not
>   have to rely on guessing BIOS drive numbers.
>
> The GRUB development team generally recommends embedding GRUB before
>   the first partition, unless you have special requirements. You must
>   ensure that the first partition starts at least 31 KiB (63 sectors)
>   from the start of the disk; on modern disks, it is often a performance
>   advantage to align partitions on larger boundaries anyway, so the first
>   partition might start 1 MiB from the start of the disk.

That means to me that ext2 is not related to embedding in any way because it's **either** embedding **or** a filesystem involved.

The question arises what you have done to produce this error message (or rather: warning). I assume this can happen if Grub2 is told to install itself into a partition instead of onto the drive itself (MBR or extended partition).

Comment: I didn't mention that my preoccupation is about the ext2 thing, I know GRUB gives crap about ext2/3/4. My interest is: 1) why the warning appears and 2) should I worry