# Extend unallocated partition into linux partition

Tags: partition, dual-boot, gparted, antergos

I am trying to somehow extend the unallocated partition (below sda1) into the sda2 partition to increase its total size. If it is relevant the sda1 is a Windows 10 parition and I'm dual-booting with Antergos (Arch Linux variant). Below is a screenshot from GParted.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mounted file systems *can't* be resized.  In the screenshot of `gparted`, there's a *key* symbol between */dev/sda2* and *ext4*; that key symbol indicates */dev/sda2* is mounted.  It can't be unmounted while the Arch Linux system on *sda2* is running.

To fix:

1. Reboot from a liveCD, (or USB equivalent), and run `gparted` from that, right click on */dev/sda2* and click 'Resize/Move', etc.  Now */dev/sda2* won't be mounted, so it can be resized.
2. Usually after moving the root directory, `grub` should be updated, or it won't be able to find the system, and Arch wouldn't boot.  So after the resize, (and still using the liveCD), open a terminal, do [the appropriate `chroot` login to */dev/sda2*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue?rq=1), and run `update-grub`.
3. Reboot, remove liveCD.  The system should now boot from the newly resized 120GB */dev/sda2* Arch Linux partition.

Comment: +1. as long as the partition number doesn't get changed (or the partition's UUID if using them wih grub), there's no need to run `update-grub`.

Comment: @cas, no, the part # and UUID wouldn't be changed.  But if the hard drive is such that `grub` [can only be installed using *blocklists*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174206/warning-file-system-ext2-doesnt-support-embedding-but-my-system-isnt-emb), a partition resize can break that, and a `chroot` et al will be needed.  (I've bumped into this annoyance several times now...)

Comment: OK.  I don't think I've ever encountered that.  I can't even remember the last time i had any need to install grub to a partition rather than the MBR, and I always create the first partition at, e.g. 2MB, so that the partitions are properly aligned for all common and foreseeable sector sizes...so there's **always** more than enough room for grub to embed into the space between the MBR and the first sector.